# auto line numbering UITextView in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, syntax

this photo will explain what I mean by auto-numbering in UITextView
[image]

I found this code works fine but I have this annoying Yellow warning

**Error :**
substring(to:)' is deprecated: Please use String slicing subscript with a 'partial range upto operator.

**suggestions :** and if there is any other way to do it, `func`, other methods,  I will be happy to try it

```
var currentLine: Int = 1

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        
     if  (textView.text.isEmpty && !text.isEmpty) {
         textView.text = "\(currentLine). "
         currentLine += 1
        }
     else {
         if text.isEmpty {
             if textView.text.count >= 4 {
                 let str = textView.text.substring(to:textView.text.index(textView.text.endIndex, offsetBy: -4))
                    if str.hasPrefix("\n") {
                        textView.text = String(textView.text.dropLast(3))
                        currentLine -= 1
                    }
                }
                else if text.isEmpty && textView.text.count == 3 {
                    textView.text = String(textView.text.dropLast(3))
                    currentLine = 1
                }
            }
            else {
                let str = textView.text.substring(from:textView.text.index(textView.text.endIndex, offsetBy: -1))
                if str == "\n" {
                    textView.text = "\(textView.text!)\(currentLine). "
                    currentLine += 1
                }
            }

        }
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below line in your code.

```
    let str = textView.text[..<textView.text.index(textView.text.endIndex, offsetBy: -4)]
```